# data ingestion from S3 into DynamoDB continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis-firehose

we have our application that ingests data to S3 via Kinesis Firehose. we want this data to also flow to DynamoDB.

We can do it by AWS lambda but it will be an expensive approach as the streams will be continuously sending data.

what other choices are out there to achieve this? how have you solved this problem of moving data from s3 to dynamodb?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, Firehose does not support delivering to DynamoDB afaik, so you will probably need to pick one of two options:

1. S3 -> Lambda (triggered by S3 changes) -> DynamoDB
2. Kinesis -> Lambda -> DynamoDB

If you can attach your Lambda directly to Kinesis I would choose 2-nd approach, as it reduces number of steps required for data to end up in DynamoDB.

If you don't want to use AWS Lambda for whatever reason you can always implement your own Kinesis consumer using KCL library (for 2-nd approach).